# Is there a way converting String to SolrDocumentlist?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mockmvc, solrclient

I am trying to write MockMVC test for a searchController where I want to mock entry point of solr data to the api. So that my api do the rest of the sorting stuff and through mockMVC test I can validate the service.

```
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@WebMvcTest(SeaController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
class SeaControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @MockBean
    private SeaService seaService;

    @MockBean
    MesService mesService;

    @MockBean
    private SeaCommand seaCommand;

    @MockBean
    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    
    private SolrDocumentList mockedSolrDocList ;
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();

    }

    @Test
    public void findByQuery() throws Exception {
        String jsonBody = (Files.readString(Paths.get("local path to /payload.txt")));
        String responseBody = (Files.readString(Paths.get("local path to /response.txt")));
        
        //solrDoc contains list of SolrDocs 
        String mockSolrdocList = (Files.readString(Paths.get("local path to /solrDoc.txt")));
        
        //getting null pointer exception for below line
        when(mockedSolrDocList.toString()).thenReturn(mockSolrdocList);

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/query")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .characterEncoding("utf-8")
                        .content(jsonBody)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString(responseBody)));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please give some more detail? May be a code snippet for which you want to write the test?

Comment: @A G added code and description for reference

Answer (score 0):

You "forgot" to mock `mockedSolrDocList`! ;)

Or ([annotate](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mock.html)):

```
@Mock
private SolrDocumentList mockedSolrDocList;
```

Or ([initialize](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mock(java.lang.Class))):

```
//...
mockedSolrDocList = /*Mockito.*/mock(SolrDocumentList.class);
```

Both will:

- create a mock object. (which is eligible for `when`, `verify`,...)
- eliminate the NPE.